# Alternating row background in QTextTable

Tags: qt, datatable, background-color, qtextdocument, qtextcursor

I am trying to create a printable document using `QTextDocument`, which also includes a table, which I am adding using `QTextCursor::insertTable`.
However I have the requirement to use different background colors for the table rows. The table is meant to contain all days of a month, and weekends should have grey background, while workdays shall have no background.

I have tried this code:

```
    QTextTable* table = cursor.insertTable(1, 7, normal);   // 7 columns, and first row containing header

    foreach (DayItem* day, month->days)
    {
        if (day->date.dayOfWeek() == 6 || day->date.dayOfWeek() == 7)
        {
            table->setFormat(background);       // grey background
            table->appendRows(1);
        }
        else
        {
            table->setFormat(normal);           // white background
            table->appendRows(1);
        }
    }
```

Now the issue with this is that the `table->setFormat` changes the format of the **whole** table, and I can't seem to find any function which lets me set the format for a **row** or a **cell**. There is formatting options for cells, however those are for the **text format**, and thus would not color the cell background.

I have also tried using `QTextDocument::insertHTML` and work with HTML tables, however Qt would not render the CSS correctly which I would use for styling the borders and so on.

How can I achieve alternating row background colors in `QTextTable`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [QTextTableCell:setFormat](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtexttablecell.html#setFormat) to change the background color of each cell:

```
auto edit = new QTextEdit();

auto table = edit->textCursor().insertTable(3, 2);
for(int i = 0; i < table->rows(); ++i)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < table->columns(); ++j)
    {
        auto cell = table->cellAt(i, j);
        auto cursor = cell.firstCursorPosition();
        cursor.insertText(QString("cell %1, %2").arg(i).arg(j));

        auto format = cell.format();
        format.setBackground(i%2 == 0 ? Qt::red : Qt::green);
        cell.setFormat(format);
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot try out your example because I decided to use `QWebEngineView` meanwhile to render the contents. Nevertheless I am going to accept the answer.